# Sencha Touch Cordova app gives blank white screen on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ipad

I have a sencha touch cordova app which works perfectly fine on Iphones, to get it past the apple review I need to make it work on iPads too. I do not intend to support iPad users at this point of time so have kept the Devices as iPhone only in the settings. I expect the app to open in iPhone resolution on the iPad and works similar to the iphone - but it doesn't, when i install and run it on the iPad, all I get is a blank white screen and nothing happens further. On the xcode console I get this :

```
WARNING: The splashscreen image named LaunchImage-700 was not found
```

which is the only difference between the logs of the iphone and the ipad.
I believe it isn't getting the launch image for the iPad but I have no clue where or how to include this image.

Would be great if someone can point how to solve this issue and make my app work on an ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error after updating xcode. They got really picky about what splash screen sizes you can use.

I use this plugin on npm [cordova-splash](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash). This builds all different sizes of splash screens and my xcode automatically picked them up.

Usage is really simple just make sure you have a `splash.png` file in the root folder of your cordova project and run `cordova-splash`

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. It worked to get the warning out, but now I get a blank white screen after the splash screen and nothing happens there after. I suspect this has something to do with my code. As I haven't written any iPad specific code - guess I will have to add it. I am marking this answer as correct since it solved my issue. Also one mistake that I was doing initially was firing `sencha build app native` after `cordova-splash` which replaced all my images and it wouldn't work again. So for anyone reading this question the order should be `sencha build app native` then `cordova-splash`